# Determine whether a language belong to R,RE\R,coRE\R or other

Tags: computer-science, computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

For the following language, determine to which class it belongs

> $$L_3=\left\{\langle M\rangle\Big\vert|\langle M\rangle|\le 2016\text{ and M is a TM that accepts }\varepsilon \right\}$$

I've seen an answer which claimed that this is a finite language, thus it is decidable. Unfortunately, I do not understand why it is finite.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is $\langle M\rangle$?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo, it is the encoding of $M$.

Comment: An what precisely is the encoding of a Turing machine?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: What does "$\vert M\vert<2016$" mean? What is $\vert M\vert$? And, how many Turing machines are there of a given size in this sense?

(I am assuming here that *I* know what you mean by $\vert M\vert$ - you should clarify what this notation means - but I have a very strong guess.)

Comment: I had a typo, it should be $|\langle M \rangle|$, please refer to the corrected version of my question.

Comment: @Galc127 My hint still stands. What does $\vert \langle M\rangle\vert$ mean?

Comment: Is Andres and Noah's hints clear to you or do you still need more help?